# How to update the firmware of a T16 Pro's internal multiprotocol module?

Tags: t16, firmware, multiprotocol-module

How should I go about updating the internal multiprotocol module firmware of my Jumper T16 Pro?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to do is to check that you have the bootloader. Newer radios should have it installed. (Just check that you have Multiprotocol Module firmware v1.2.1.85 or later) If you don't have the bootloader installed, here is a video on how: [Jumper T16 "Update Recommended" Fix (how to flash internal multiprotocol module)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PSLgG3QhSg).

Assuming you have the bootloader, the next step is to go here: [MULTI-Module Firmware Downloads](https://downloads.multi-module.org/). Here, you can get the latest firmware for any multiprotocol module, so this works for more than just the T16. On the left, find the module that you want to update. In this case, the Jumper T16 Pro Internal module.

[image: module selection]

After that, most of the information is filled out so just fill in the rest (in this case just channel order)

[image]

Get the file that corresponds to the channel order of your radio:

[image: Firmware files]

Put the file onto the `FIRMWARE` folder of the micro SD card from the Jumper T16 and then put the card into the T16 and power it on. Long press the system key, press the page button once, scroll down to `[FIRMWARE]` and click it, long-press the new file, and then Flash Internal Multi.

If you need a more comprehensive guide, check out Joshua Bardwell's video: [Jumper T16 "Update Recommended" Bootloader Method (how to flash internal multiprotocol module)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qT_wmbxTBp8).

Comment: This is perfect - I just ordered the TX16S! Thanks for the guide!

Comment: Nice answer - easy to follow!